# Decide whether regular language contains a word $w$ for which $|w| = n^2$

Tags: regular-languages, decision-problem

**Task:**

Input: DFA $M = (Z, Σ, δ, q_S, E)$
$T(M)$ := Language that $M$ accepts.
Question: Does $T(M)$ contain at least one word $w$ such that $|w| = n^2$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$$ ?$

**My attempt:**

Since the language $\{w\in Σ^* \mid |w| = n^2 \} $is not regular. You cannot create DFA $M'$ which accepts this language and use it somehow.

If $M$ is finite (which is decidable) you can check each word so this is not a problem.

If $M$ is not finite there has to be a cycle from a productive state. I have drawn a couple simple DFAs and I have noticed that there is DFA's with cycles that don't contain such word $w$.

Then I tried to find the property of the cycle/DFA so that there has to be a $w$ with $|w| = n^2$
and noticed that the following equation has to be true:
$$n^2 = d + ck$$ with $d$ being the distance from the initial state $q_s$ to an accepting state $q_e \in E$ and $c$ being the length of the cycle somewhere on the path from $q_s$ to $q_e$.

Therefore: $$\sqrt{d+ck} \in \mathbb{N}$$
However I don't know how to continue from here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is $n$ an input of the problem?

Comment: No it has to be any $n$

Comment: Also why is your equation $n^2 = d+ck$ and not $2^n = d + ck$?

Comment: Thank you that is a mistake sorry.

Comment: Rather than answering clarification questions in the comments, please [edit] the question to clarify, and make sure that the question reads well for someone who encounters the question for the first time and they can understand what is being asked without having to read the comments.

Comment: What is your question?  Do you want to know of any algorithm to solve this (regardless of how fast or slow it is)?  Do you want to know whether there is a polynomial-time algorithm?  Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert $M$ to an NFA over $\Sigma = \{a\}$ by renaming all labels on edges to $a$. The language accepted by the NFA has the same word lengths as $T(M)$. Convert the NFA to a DFA. After removing unreachable states, the DFA is a path leading to a cycle. This implies that the set of length of words in $T(M)$ is eventually periodic. This means that for some there exist some $k,m$ and sets $S \subseteq \{0,\ldots,k-1\}$ and $T \subseteq \{0,\ldots,m-1\}$ such that the lengths of word in $T(M)$ are
$$ S \cup \bigcup_{i \in T} \{ nm + k + i : n \in \mathbb{N} \}. $$
We have reduced your problem to the following:

> Given $a > 0$ and $b \ge 0$, decide whether $\{na + b : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ contains a square.

If $na + b = r^2$ for some $r$ then $b \equiv r^2 \pmod{a}$, and so $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $a$. Conversely, suppose that $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $a$. Then there exists $r$ such that $b \equiv r^2 \pmod{a}$, say $r^2 = b + za$, where $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. For any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
(ma + r)^2 = a(m^2a + 2mr) + r^2 = a(m^2 a + 2mr + z) + b.
$$
Choosing $m = |z|$, this is of the form $na + b$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We have shown that $\{na + b : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ contains a square iff $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $a$, which is a decidable property.

Comment: What's the meaning of k and m? That (and what you do with them) isn't clear to me.

Comment: Here $m$ is the length of the period, and $k$ is the length of the part in the sequence which is not periodic. In terms of the graph of the DFA, it has a path of length $k$ leading to a cycle of length $m$.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I realized it must indeed *only* be a path+cycle and edited that out. I was thinking of the original DFA having two cycles of different lengths, for example one accepting lengths that are multiples of 3 and the other accepting multiples of 5. But since you converted to a DFA over a single letter, I realized it can't have "branches" and thus will be a cycle of length 15, with accepting states at the proper places.

Comment: Your $na + b = r^2$ is the same as my $n^2 = ck + d$ correct?

Comment: I use my own notation, but it has the correct semantics.

Comment: $n^2 = ck + d <=> n^2 - d = ck <=>d ≡ n^2 $(mod  c) That is correct.
So if there is a cycle with on a path of lenght d which has a cycly of lenght c we can check it.

My question is now what If we have multiple cycles on the same path with cycles lenghts $c_1$ and  $c2$ such that each of them individually does not fullfill the requirement and $gcd(c_1, c_2) =1$ can there still be a solution? 

I have found an example for which there is a sollution.
Say $c_1 = 3, c_2 = 5$ and $d = 2$ then individually the cycles have no sollution but together there is a sollution with $2 + 5*4 + 3*9 = 49$

Comment: You can’t have multiple cycles. There is only one cycle.

Comment: If you take (aaaaaaaa)* | (bbbbbbbbbbbbb)* then you started with two cycles of length 8 and 13 in parallel. Since you don't care about the symbols, you have a cycle of length lcm(8, 13) = 104 and 8, 16, 24, etc. symbols before you entered the cycle. If you had two sequential cycles of lengths 8 and 13, that's converted to 1 cycle of length gcd(8, 13) = 1 and many possible number of symbols until you enter the cycle. So the possible lengths are n * cycle length, plus a finite number of symbols before you enter and after you exit the cycle.

Comment: You cannot exit a cycle.

Comment: The possible lengths of strings in the language is either a finite set, or its the set of all a*n +b_i for 1 or more different fixed b_i ≥ 0, a ≥ 1, and all natural numbers n. A simple case would be (a | aa | aaa) aaaa* with possible lengths 4n + 1 / 2 / 3. And there is a square length with b_i = 1, lengths 1, 2, 3, 5,  6, 7, 9, 10, 11 ... of which some are squares. There's more than one case b_i to test, that's the whole difference

Comment: Oh you are right with your construction it's not possible for it to have multiple cycyles because it is a DFA with only one symbol so if it enters a cycle it cannot leave it otherwise it would not be deterministic.